# Why ndarray object with different id change simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code confuses me. I know `d` has a different id with `c`, but why changing `d` lead to changes in `c`?

```
c=np.zeros(4)
d = c[:]
print(id(d))
print(id(c))
d[0] = 1
print(d)
print(c)
```

output:

```
2073635240496
2073589009424
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason that happens is because of the layers of this object:**

```
print(type(c))
print(type(c[0]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

#### As you can see, `c` is a nested `class`.

Let's look at the same situation with an easier to understand, nested list:

*Without `deepcopy`:*

```
a = [[3,8],[4,4]]
b = a[:]

print(a)
print(b)

b[0][0] = 9

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 8], [4, 4]]
[[3, 8], [4, 4]]
[[9, 8], [4, 4]]
[[9, 8], [4, 4]]
```

---

*With `deepcopy`:*

```
from copy import deepcopy

a = [[3,8],[4,4]]
b = deepcopy(a)

print(a)
print(b)

b[0][0] = 9

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[3, 8], [4, 4]]
[[3, 8], [4, 4]]
[[3, 8], [4, 4]]
[[9, 8], [4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set a variable to another variable that is a list, both variables are assigned to the same exact list, so changes in the list will appear in both variables. I would just replace `d = c[:]` to `d = c[:].copy()`.

Comment: if c was a normal Python list, `d = c[:]` does a shallow copy so `d = c[:].copy()` is superfluous
The issue arrises becuase of the way numpy builds it's array, and the OP needs to do a deepcopy of c in order to copy the nested arrays.